Database memory limit
I want to create a test lab used by developers, one of the VMs will be running griddb as a database. I want to restrict the database engine memory usage by running "gs_paramconf -u admin/ --set storeMemoryLimit 4096MB" as described here https://griddb.net/en/docs/GridDB_OperationGuide.html.
However, the change doesn't persist, and after some time, when I run "gs_paramconf -u admin/ --show storeMemoryLimit", the value is reseted to the default one.
Could you please advise how should I proceed?
Thank you

configuration changes made using gs_paramconf command only work until the service is restarted, so it will be reverted after each server shutdown. To change configuration permanently, you need to change storeMemoryLimit parameter in the Node definition file. It is located at /var/lib/gridstore/conf/gs_node.json.
Thank you
